# Laravel 4 redirect issue with login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 and here is my AdminController file :

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {


  protected $layout = "admin.layout";

  public function __construct() { 

// security for the forms and access
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
$this->beforeFilter('auth.admin' , array('except' =>array('getIndex','postSignin')));

   // using this one to display user value if login and is admin
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
    $this->user = Auth::getUser();
    View::share('user', $this->user);
   }
    }

   // main admin page
   public function getIndex(){
$this->layout->content = View::make('admin.login');

    }


     // get the dashboard page
    public function getDashboard() {
      $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard');
     }


     // missing pages all redirect to dashboard if user is logged in.
      public function missingMethod($parameters = array()){
   if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        $this->getDashboard();
   else
        $this->getIndex();
}
```

Here is my filters.php file :

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function()
 {

    if(!Auth::check() && !(Auth::user()->isAdmin())){

    return Redirect::guest('admin');

}


 });
```

in my routes.php file I am doing this:

```
 Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

here is what I want if you could help me :_

1) . I want to clean up my code where there is not that much checking for if user is logged and isAdmin.

2). right now if you are logged in and you go to "admin/" , it will show you the login page ? how could I fix it in an effective way.

3). also if you are not logged in and you go to "admin/dashboard" it will show you dashboard content ? how to fix

Thank you in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use route groups and use a single filter to validate them

Check the docs

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups

Comment: how could I use that in my case?

Comment: the problem I am having is that I want to make everything secured and check ALL situations example:

Comment: So I need to remove this : $this->beforeFilter('auth.admin' , array('except' =>array('getIndex','postSignin')));
if I go with route groups?

Comment: Yes, and if you want to redirect the not logged users you should change the login of our filter, try this in your if statement:  if(!Auth::check() || !(Auth::user()->isAdmin())) <-- this will redirect to all the users that are not logged in and are not admins

Comment: the other thing is if I add this in the group route : Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController'); there is getIndex() and getDashboard() , so All the methods in thore have to go through the Auth.admin ( which if you are not an admin or not logged in , then redirect to "admin" ( index ) which also going to go through the Auth.admin filter , if I do that I get a redirect loop issue

Comment: Could you edit my code above and show me how as an example , I am getting redirect loop

Comment: Do you have only one route? or you have multiple route (each one with a controller function)?. If you have only one route then you are correct, I will suggest you to create a route for each function and then create the route groups, this way you can have more control over who can access each route

Comment: What should I do with getIndex() and getDashboard() methods? they are going to go through my check as well and here I get a redirect loop issue that is my problem :(

Comment: I only have one route : Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');

Comment: Thanks , but in your routes.php where is my other methods in AdminController going to route to?

Comment: You can add the methods to the controller with no problem, since the validation is the routes it will not affect the functionality

Comment: Still I dont think you will need the methods i delete in the example, because you use them to validate the user and this is validated by the filter

Comment: But in your routes.php you are saying this : Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('admin/login', 'AdminController@getIndex');  
}); // Doesnt that mean you only going to Auth the login page? what about the other pages?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the file http://jsfiddle.net/e3EMw/8/ , inside the group you can add any number of routes

Comment: So you mean each method I need to validate should be inside my group routes

Comment: That's correct, but is not necessarily methods, you validate Routes (a route not necessarily perform a method of a controller)

Comment: let me know if you had any issue

Comment: seems I still have issue when they go to "admin" main page ( redirect issue)  , I think there is no solution unless I add a check user in my getIndex()

Comment: I dont want to have admin/login , I just want to have when they come to admin they will see the login view , if they are of course not logged in , but if they are logged in and for some reason they go to admin it will redirect to dashboard, and vis versa , if you are not logged in and you go to the dashboard you should be redirected to "admin" main page

Comment: the thing is because im redirecting to "admin" when they are not logged in or Not isAdmin in my auth.admin , I am get a redirect loop , because I think it works like this , when I go to admin it goes to my filer and check if I am not logged in then it will redirect again to admin :) lol

Comment: try playing around with the filter and the route, you can even create more routes groups and filters to fit your requirements

Comment: thats why I had an "except" in my Auth.admin to not check the getIndex(), so basically if I do to "admin" I don't want to go redirect to admin again I just want to display the login page (if I am not logged in or redirect to dashboard if I am) you see my point??

Comment: yes i see, in this case you need three routes (index, dashboard and login)

Comment: why I need a login route? if they go to "admin/login" it will go to my missingmethod and there I check if i am logged in or not

Comment: you see my point but my code is ugly my whole thing is to try to minimize the number of times I check if users is logged in and not admin , but I can't

Comment: Again Im testing in extreme cases where if people type all cases in the url they wont be able to get access to pages unless they are logged in

Comment: I dont want admin/login page is that possible to make it only admin?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.admin'), function() {
    Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
})
```

Declare filter in `filters.php` file:

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function(){
    // Assumed you have a '/login' url
    if (Auth::guest() || (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isAdmin())) {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});
```

Also make sure you have the `user()->isAdmin()` method in your `User` model that you are using and it checks whether the user is an `admin` or not and returns a `Boolean` value, `TRUE` if the user is an admin otherwise `FALSE`.